# Overloading issue

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, complex-numbers

I'm trying to create a set of classes in order to handle complex numbers. I've seen that there is already a set of classes for the complex numbers, but because I'm learning C++ I thought it was a good idea to create a basic implementation. The problem comes up when I tried to overload the operator "/". I got a segfault and I can't understand if the problem is my implementation of the division:

complex.hpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class Complex {
  float real;
  float imm;
public:
  Complex(float new_real = 0,float new_imm = 0) {this->real = new_real;this->imm = new_imm;}
  void set(float new_real,float new_imm) {this->real = new_real; this->imm = new_imm;}
  float get_real(void) const { return this->real;}
  float get_imm(void) const { return this->imm;}
  Complex conj(void) const {Complex tmp; tmp.set(this->real,-1.0 * this->imm); return tmp;}
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Complex& cpx) {os << "Real: " << cpx.real << " Imm: " << cpx.imm << std::endl; return os; }
  friend Complex operator*(const Complex& lhs,const Complex& rhs);
  friend Complex operator+(const Complex& lhs,const Complex& rhs);
  friend Complex operator+(const Complex& lhs,const float& rhs);
};
```

complex.cpp:

```
#include "complex.hpp"


Complex operator*(const Complex& lhs,const Complex& rhs)
{
  float real_part = (lhs.real * rhs.real) - ( lhs.imm * rhs.imm);
  float imm_part = (lhs.real * rhs.imm) + ( lhs.imm * rhs.real);
  Complex result;
  result.set(real_part,imm_part);
  return result;
}

Complex operator+(const Complex& lhs,const Complex& rhs)
{
  float real_part = lhs.real + rhs.real;
  float imm_part = lhs.imm + rhs.imm;
  Complex result;
  result.set(real_part,imm_part);
  return result;
}

Complex operator+(const Complex& lhs,const float& rhs)
{
  float real_part = lhs.real + rhs;
  float imm_part = lhs.imm;
  Complex result;
  result.set(real_part,imm_part);
  return result;
}

Complex operator/(const Complex& lhs,const Complex& rhs)
{
  Complex numerator(0,0);
  numerator = rhs * rhs.conj();

  Complex denominator(0,0);
  denominator = lhs * rhs.conj();

  Complex result;
  float real_numerator = numerator.get_real();
  result = denominator / real_numerator;
  return result;
}

Complex operator/(const Complex& lhs,const float& rhs)
{
  float real_part = lhs.get_real() / rhs;
  float imm_part = lhs.get_imm() / rhs;
  Complex result;
  result.set(real_part,imm_part);
  return result;
}
```

The whole idea of the division between 2 complex is to multiply the numerator and denominator for the conjugate of the numerator in order to have only a real number on the numerator. Just to make it clear :

(a + ib) / (c + id) = ((a + ib) / (c + id)) * ((c - id) / (c - id)) = ((a + ib) * (c - id)) / (c^2 + d^2)

Now when I try to do this:

main.cpp :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Complex x(4,8);
  Complex y(3,7);
  Complex result = x / y;
  result = x / 6;
  return 0;
}
```

I got this segfault, which I don't understand:

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 2 at 0x401c56: file equalization_main.cpp, line 49.
(gdb) r
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
`/home/campiets/workspace/frontend/dfe_equalizer_fe/dev/view/src_c/test' has changed; re-reading symbols.
Starting program: /home/campiets/workspace/frontend/dfe_equalizer_fe/dev/view/src_c/test 

Breakpoint 2, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffbf08) at equalization_main.cpp:49
49    Complex x(4,8);
(gdb) n
50    Complex y(3,7);
(gdb) n
51    Complex result = x / y;
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401e64 in Complex::Complex (this=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff3feff8>, new_real=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff3feff4>, 
    new_imm=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff3feff0>) at complex.hpp:38
38    Complex(float new_real = 0,float new_imm = 0) {this->real = new_real; this->imm = new_imm;}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your error (c.f. answers), but you don't have to use `this->` everywhere, in fact just typing the name of the attribute or method will do. That said, it's perfectly legal ! Just a bit verbose (same for the `void` in parameter lists). In `Complex::conj` you could also directly use your constructor rather than `Complex::set`. There's no real need to declare any friends here either: you can actually implement all those operators as non-friend free functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Complex operator/(const Complex& lhs,const Complex& rhs)
{
  ...
  Complex denominator...;
  ...
  float real_numerator = ...;
  result = denominator / real_numerator;
  ...
}
```

That's infinite recursion.

Since the compiler hasn't seen `operator/(const Complex &lhs, const float &rhs)`, it converts the `float` argument to `Complex` and hence you get recursion.

The simplest solution is to declare or define `operator/(const Complex &lhs, const float &rhs)` before `operator/(const Complex &lhs, const Complex &rhs)`.

My preference would be to implement the operators as class members, though.  That yields simpler source code and solves the problem too.

Comment: I don't think so; the `/` here should call the overloaded `Complex operator/(const Complex& lhs,const float& rhs)`.

Comment: Is it? Doesn't `denominator / real_numerator` use the other `operator/` definition?

Comment: Just to clarify, that's because `operator/(const Complex&, const float&)` isn't visible at this point, so instead, the compiler treats that as `result = denominator / Complex(real_numerator, 0)`. I also saw the same thing when walking in the code with a debugger.

Comment: Is it? The left argument of the division is a float, so I was expecting that it was used the other implementation of the division ( complex divided by a float)

Comment: Ahh, I think @Caninonos is right.  You should add `friend Complex operator/` declarations into the definition for `Complex`; right now they are just free functions.

Comment: Step in with GDB and watch what happens. `Complex(float new_real = 0,float new_imm = 0)` should fire to turn the `float` into another `Complex` and then the looping fun begins.

Comment: @haster8558 what happens if you mark `Complex` ctor as `explicit`?

Comment: @AMA don't think that will work. It's still accepting `float`. Simple solution is to move the definition of `Complex operator/(const Complex& lhs,const float& rhs)` above `Complex operator/(const Complex& lhs,const Complex& rhs)` to make it visible.

Comment: Come to think of it Sid, you already have my upvote, but this question will benefit greatly by providing a better explanation of what went wrong, why, and a solution.

Comment: Ok, I understand why that happens. @Caninonos is right. GDB enters twice in the same division operator (complex / complex). So how can I make visible the other overloaded function ( complex / float)?

Comment: @haster8558 forward declare it ! (or just move its definition before the other operator/) That's what you did (unintentionally ?) when you declared all those friend operators (you can also do it outside of class scope without the friend keyword). That basically tells the compiler "that function exists, but I don't want to define what it does yet".

Comment: Compiling happens in order.  Anything declared after a function does not exist. Move the operator with the `float` ahead of the `/` with the two`Complex` in the file. No need for a forward declaration here, and the forward declaration adds another line of code you can get wrong.

Comment: @Caninonos Thanks, I'll do like you said and I'll let you know. Thanks!!!

Comment: @user4581301 it will work: it would not accept float. Of course, this does not solve the problem, but at least it changes it to a compile-time problem, which is handy :)

Comment: @user4581301, I agree.  Thanks!

Comment: I didn't spot the missing declaration inside the class for the "/" operator. As soon as I added them everything started to work properly. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 3):

The function

```
Complex operator/(const Complex& lhs,const Complex& rhs) { ... }
```

causes stack overflow since the line

```
result = denominator / real_numerator;
```

ends up being interpreted as:

```
result = denominator / Complex(real_numerator);
```

You can resolve that problem by defining or declaring

```
Complex operator/(const Complex& lhs, const float& rhs)
```

before it.

If you change your code to use:

```
Complex operator/(const Complex& lhs,const float& rhs)
{
   return Complex(lhs.get_real()/rhs, lhs.get_imm()/rhs);
}

Complex operator/(const Complex& lhs,const Complex& rhs)
{
   ...
}
```

your program will work ok.

---

A suggestion for simplifying the above `operator/` function.

If you add the following member function

```
float magnitude_square() const { return (real*real + imm*imm); }
```

then you can use

```
Complex operator/(const Complex& lhs,const Complex& rhs)
{
   return (lhs * rhs.conj())/rhs.magnitude_square());
}
```